# What Happens to Email Id and Username When Refreshing a Partial Copy Sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

I wanted to know what will happen to my email id after refreshing my partial copy sandbox.
I also want to know if usernames will be same as production or not?

Answer (score 2):

**UserName** will append the sandbox name. If your sandbox name is "uat" and your username in prod is myuser@gmail.com then the refreshed sandbox username would be myuser@gmail.com.uat

In case of **email**, it makes email invalid. eg if your email in live was myemail@gmail.com after refresh in sandbox it will make it as myemail=gmail.com@example.com.

Comment: and `Email Deliverability` is changed to System on sandbox refresh as well

Answer (score 1):

Your username is the same as prod, with the name of the sandbox appended, for example if you called your sandbox "sandbox":

- Prod: yourname@somewhere.com.prod
- SB:   yourname@somewhere.com.prod.sandbox

Your password will remain the same as production.

Comment: Do you mean that after refreshing it will append .sandbox name to my username by default or do we manually update them through dataloader later? What about email id? No change in it?

Comment: If your sandbox name is "sb" it will append that to your username (and email as mentioned in the other answer). So you often need to fix the email address immediately after a refresh because at that point the email is not a valid one.

Comment: Hi Caspar and Pranay, Thanks for clarifying it. I have one last question. When we refresh partial copy sandbox by using sandbox template,  I believe that data will come randomly but let say I want 1000 accounts and their associated opportunities and cases without missing anything on the data. Will it be possible? I heard that not all opportinuties and cases associated with accounts will come after refresh. Everything is random. Is it correct?